# Выборка всех последних сообщений из всех диалогов

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица Message:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне выбрать все последние сообщения из диалогов. То есть из всех диалогов только 1 последнее сообщение - с наибольшей датой.

Например для юзера с id = 4, есть 3 диалога с юзерамы с id=5,3,1.
В диалоге между юзерами 5-4 будут сообщения (105),
между юзерами 1-4 будут сообщения (103,102,101,100) ...

Так вот, среди всех диалогов мне нужно выбрать все самые последние сообщения.

В данном примере, это будут сообщения: 103,104,105.

Еще есть дополнение, **если выйдет запрос для нахождения описанного выше**, то как еще сделать исключение для найденного списка. Например, есть массив-список с id пользователей сообщения от которых не должны показываться. Пусть там есть reject_id(12,5,21). Значит сообщение 105 не должно находится в запросе, т.к. его прислал пользователь с id=5.

Помогите плиз, бьюсь уже часа 3-4. Вот рекомендовали примерно [это](http://www.sql.ru/forum/687908/faq-vyborka-pervoy-posledney-zapisi-v-gruppah?mid=7543220#7543220) , но у меня еще более усложненное условие, не могу сообразить.

Comment: закиньте данные текстом, в идеале на http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @splash58 Я здесь впервые, не в курсе что да как нужно сделать на  sqlfiddle.com. Но вроде вот так вышло (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b86e/1)

Comment: я написал, надеюсь, придут профи и предложат что-нить поэффективней :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант, который меня устраивает, для моей не "очень хорошей" структуры данных)) :

```
SELECT * FROM `Message`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT max(id) as id FROM
        (SELECT id, fromUserId, toUserId FROM `Message` WHERE fromUserId =4
            UNION ALL
        SELECT id, toUserId, fromUserId FROM `Message` WHERE toUserId =4) t
    GROUP BY fromUserId, toUserId
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: я написал update в вопросе в качестве коммента к вашему ответу

Answer (score 0):

```
select `id`,`msg` 
from `Message` m  
where sendDate = 
        (select max(sendDate) 
           from `Message` n  
           where n.fromUserId=m.fromUserId and n.toUserId=m.toUserId) 
group by  `fromUserId` , `toUserId`
```

[**Демо на sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b463d/8)

А вот это со вторым условием

```
SELECT `id`,`fromUserId` , `toUserId` ,`msg` 
  FROM `Message` m  
   where sendDate = 
            (select max(sendDate) FROM `Message`n  
                 where n.fromUserId=m.fromUserId and n.toUserId=m.toUserId) 
      and fromUserId not in (select id from reject)
      and toUserId not in (select id from reject)
    group by  `fromUserId` , `toUserId`
```

[**Демо на sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49546/1)

**UPDATE** Комментарий к ответу автора вопроса. Я бы не стал выбирать последние по максимальному значению id. Если автоинкремент когда-нить переполнится, или вы перезапустите его с нуля, чтобы использовать освободившиеся номера, ваша схема даст сбой. Давайте чуть-чуть поправим запрос, чтобы он работал с датами

```
SELECT * FROM `Message`
WHERE sendDate IN (
  SELECT max(sendDate) as id FROM
        (SELECT fromUserId, toUserId, sendDate FROM `Message` WHERE fromUserId =4
            UNION ALL
        SELECT toUserId, fromUserId, sendDate FROM `Message` WHERE toUserId =4) t
    GROUP BY fromUserId, toUserId)
```

[**Демо на sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1a07/12)

Comment: Нет находит не то что мне нужно, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: @MaksTarasenko я неправильно понял, что вы хотите?

Comment: я добавил ответ, посмотрите что он находит. 
Нужны все последние сообщения со всех диалогов для конкретного юзера. То есть для юзера с id=4 должно вернуть только три сообщения, т.к. у него только три диалога.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id, m.msg from message m, 
       (select id_from, id_to, max(id) id from (
           select IF(fromUserId > toUserId, fromUserId, toUserId) id_from,
                  IF(fromUserId < toUserId, fromUserId, toUserId) id_to,
        sendDate, id from message) f
group by f.id_from, f.id_to) r
where m.id = r.id
  and (m.toUserId in (4)  
  or m.fromUserId in (4))
```

Comment: Спасибо @Vitamin! Супер! Но только данный запрос выберет все последние сообщения со всех диалогов. А как выбрать только для конкретного пользователя. Например с id=4 ???